# Embedding PHP wont work with Apache Lounge

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I've been setting up an environment for html/php using Apache Lounge.  Although my html worked fine, I started noticing issues after I tried to embed php.  When I do only php, it just prints everything how it is, including the tags.  When I try to embed it in html, it simply skips over all php parts, but sometimes prints the tags randomly.  Yes, my file is .php.  When looking at other people's similar questions, I found many saying to `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php7 .html` or `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`.  However, I have no such file anywhere, and both people who suggested that were using XAMPP.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have installed `php` `libapache2-mod-php` `php-mcrypt php-mysql`?

Comment: For the second two, I got a "Could not find a version that satisfies..." when trying to install using pip.  Any ideas?  I tried all combinations of changing libapache to libapache24 or mod-php to mod-php72

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Update: CSS is also not working.  I don't know if that makes anything more clear.